# How to store a sequence of events related to a transaction

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, sequence

I am using Sql Server 2008 R2.

I have two tables that describe import processes and export processes.
Import table has these columns with others that just have details about each type of import

`ImportID, ImportFileFormat, ImportFileLocation,...`

The Export tbl is similar to the import table except it describes outputs and other export specific data.

`ExportID, ExportFileFormat, ExportFileLocation,...`

Now I need some way of storing a 'Transaction' and I am stuck on how to do this exactly.

A 'transaction' is any number of imports and exports in any unique sequence.  Eg: `T = I1, E1, E2` or `I2, E1, E3, I1` or `I1` or `E3` or any unique combination of importing / exporting with no limit to number of Imports/ exports.

A 'transaction' may eventually include other 'eventtypes' other than just import/export like 'run_sp' or some sort of action in the database or application.

How might I go about doing something like this? I have looked at what I think may be a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488249/storing-the-events-of-a-pokerhand-in-a-data-base) on stackoverflow. This seems like something that may do what I want but I am unsure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit #1:

tblTransactions:

```
TransactionID   TransactionNumber   EventTable   EventID
1               1                   'tblImport'  1
2               1                   'tblExport'  3
3               2                   'tblImport'  1
4               3                   'tblExport'  3
5               2                   'tblExport'  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have a transactions table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Transactions(TransactionID INT IDENTITY(1,1));
```

When you're about to start a new transaction (a set of imports and exports), do this:

```
DECLARE @tID INT;
INSERT dbo.Transactions DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT @tID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Now in your import and export tables, add a column that holds the transaction id, and store @tID there for every action in this sequence.

Or use a separate table to store Transaction + Event combinations, if events can be recycled. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TransactionEvents
(
  TransactionID INT,   -- foreign key
  EventTypeID TINYINT, -- 1 = import, 2 = export
  EventID INT,         -- implicit foreign key to import/export table
  ... other columns ...
);
```

You can have a lookup table for EventTypes if you want, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EventTypes
(
  EventTypeID TINYINT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name SYSNAME UNIQUE
);
INSERT dbo.EventTypes VALUES(1,N'Import'),(2,N'Export');
```

You might also consider not having separate import and export tables, but one events table with a type of import or export. Then the foreign key here can be explicit.

And please ditch the `tbl` prefixes. All they do is make you type three extra characters every single time.

Comment: I don't want to add another column to the import export tables because I want to 'reuse' those rows. If I were to do it that way I would have to create a new row in the import export table for every transaction. If I were to create a transaction table how could I define a transaction that may change.(just a new row?)

Comment: Then I think you need to better explain exactly what you want. I can't piece it together from these random word problems, sorry. Can you use a M:N junction table of sorts (TransactionID, ImportID NULL, ExportID NULL)

Comment: @Archangel33 I don't think you understand what Aaron is suggesting.  You have a row in the transaction table for every event, but your import/export tables don't change at all.  They are referred to in the transaction table but not changed themselves.

Comment: So is the suggestion something like Edit#1?

Comment: @Archangel33 well can you explain why you need a TransactionID *and* a TransactionNumber? And why if you only have a couple of types of events, you need to store a string for every one? Why not just have a surrogate represent that (e.g. EventType, where Import = 1, Export = 2, etc.)? And why do you need a `tbl` prefix on your table? What else could it be other than a table?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand The TransactionID is just a unique row ID I don't necessarily need it, I have a column like that in every table I have. The 'TransactionNumber' is a way for me to define all the events that go with each other(link all events together). I could just use a surrogate to represent that. The `tbl` prefix is just a convention I use just like all stored procedures are prefixed with `sp_` or views with `v_` most of which are just to be very explicit.

Comment: They don't help anything (so now you open the Tables node in Object Explorer, and everything is prefixed by `tbl` - this just makes it harder to find the table you're after). Also please see [this article about the sp_ prefix, which you absolutely should not be using](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Well I can't change the `tbl` prefix thing thats just the way my place of business does it.(for now) That was a very good read I had no idea. I see what you mean and I'll have to go back through the things i've touched to fix this. Thankfully that won't be much, as you might have figured out I am still new to SQL and have yet to do anything of significance in the DB. I appreciate the info lord knows I need all I can get. Also, to set the order of the events would I then just add a column with ints to represent 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.. Conservetly spaced ex: 10, 20, 30, etc...?

Comment: Sure, if sequence doesn't match EventID ranking then yes, that would fall under `...other columns...`

Comment: Also note that if the TransactionEvents table indicates a date/time the event started/finished, and your sequence means the same thing mine does (ordered chronologically), there is no reason to store such a thing, because you can always derive it using window functions like ROW_NUMBER() and DENSE_RANK(). Storing it just wastes space and adds another value you need to maintain.